# Backup and Restore events TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know there are Backup and Restore events Report in SQL Server 2008, is there a TSQL command to do the same?

The report gives information like the following

- Datetime
- Destination
- Restore Type
- Mode
- Recovery Option
- User
- Backup Name

I am guessing this is in a system table somewhere but my google search have not found anything yet.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following query to get the last restore date for databases that exisit using the following SQL.

> SELECT
>         Max([restore_date]) as LastRestoreDate
>         ,[destination_database_name]   FROM [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory]
>   inner join sys.databases on
>   [destination_database_name] = name
>   group by [destination_database_name]

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

run this query which will return the tables names that contains the data you looking for

```
Use[msdb]
select * from sysobjects where (name like '%restore%' or name like '%backup%') and type='U'
```

Comment: @Microprecessor, I am looking for report source, not the action of restoring, thanks anyway.

Comment: I think these information are stored inside `msdb` system database, check my answer I edited it.

Comment: @Microprecessor, thanks again not what I looking for, actually found the system table i was looking for, see answer below.